# Reduce the computation time of fixed matrix and random vector multiplication $Ax$ and/or $x^HAx$

Tags: matrices

If I have a fixed (known, unchangable) matrix $A$ of dimension $n\times n$, and a random vector $x$ of dimension $n$, is it possible to calculate the $Ax$ and/or $x^HAx$ with complexity less than $O(n^2)$ with some pre-computed intermediate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the calculation of $Ax$ needs at least $\sim n^2$ complex multiplications ($\times$).

For $x^*Ax$, I assume that $A$ is hermitian and that we calculated its Gauss decomposition in squares.

EDIT 1. That follows is a reference in french language  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9duction_de_Gauss

EDIT 2. The Gauss decomposition does not need the calculation of the eigenvalues. This decomposition is essentially in the following triangular form: $x^*Ax=\sum_i \pm|\sum_{j\geq i}u_{ij}x_j|^2$. Then the calculation of a certain $y^*Ay$  needs $\sim n^2/2$ $\times$.

Comment: Would you please do me a favor to point out any reference I can found of 'the Gauss decomposition in squares'? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi loup blanc, thanks for your reply. Would you please explain more about how you get the triangular form: $x^*Ax=\sum_i \pm|\sum_{j\geq i}u_{ij}x_j|^2$? I think time reduction of factor of 2 is also good. The reference seems only talking about the eigen-decomposition.

Comment: @ george andrew , if you are interested by my post, then upvote it.

Comment: Thanks loup blanc, I am sorry I am not very familiar with the system. I've just voted for the answer, but didn't see score change FYI.

Comment: @ george andrew , upvoting requires at least 15 points. Have a look on my edit.

Comment: @ loup blanc, now I might understand your idea.It's quite elegant.Thank you again.